# Writing a list to a text file

Tags: python-3.x

“Write a program that prompts users for their names, when they respond, write their names to a file"..

```
users = []

While True:
    name = input('What is    your name?..\n')
    users.append(name)
for user in users:
    File = 'usernames.txt'
    with open(File, 'w') as entries:
        entries.write(user)
```

It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be stuck in an infinite while loop before even writing the user names into a file.

First thing that you have to think about - a condition in which you stop asking for new user names, for example if the user enters `"stop"`.

The other thing - is writing to the file. When you use `'w'` as `open` mode, the file will be overriden each time you call `write()`. So if you want to write each name separately, use appending mode `'a'`.

Here's how the code snippet can look:

```
users = []

while True:
    name = input('What is your name?..\n')

    if name == 'stop':
        break # getting out of the loop
        
    users.append(name)

for user in users:
    file_name = 'usernames.txt'
    with open(file_name, 'a') as file:
        file.write(user + '\n')
```

Inputs:

```
What is your name?..
a
What is your name?..
b
What is your name?..
c
What is your name?..
d
What is your name?..
stop
```

File contents:

```
a
b
c
d
```

Alternativaly, you can write the whole list at one time:

```
with open(file_name, 'w') as file:
    file.write("\n".join(users))
```

Or each time you receive a new name (except for `stop`).